# How to handle large strings in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I've got a question about testing methods working on strings. Everytime, I write a new test on a method that has a string as a parameter.

Now, some issues come up:

- How to include a test string with \n, \r, \t, umlauts etc?
- How to set the encoding?
- Should I use external files that are opened by a FileInputStream? (too much overhead, imho)

So... what are your approaches to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to include a test string with \n, \r, \t, umlauts etc?

Um... just type it the way you want? You can use \n, \r and \t, umlauts stc. in Java String literals; if you're worried about the encoding of the source code file, you can use [Unicode escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Escape_Sequences), and you can produce them using the native2ascii tool that comes with the JDK.

> How to set the encoding?

Once you have a Java String, it's too late to worry about encodings - they use UTF-16, and any encoding problems occur when translating between Strings and byte arrays (unlike C, Java keeps these concepts clearly separate)

**Edit:**
If your Strings are too big to be comfortably used in source code or you're really worried about the treatment of line breaks and white space, then keeping each String in a separate file is probably best; in that case, the encoding must be specified when reading the file (In the constructor of `InputStreamReader`)

Answer (score 3):

- If you have a lot of them, keep test strings in separate class with string consts
- Try not to keep the files on disk unless you must. I agree with your claim - this brings too much overhead (not to mention what happens if you start getting I/O errors)
- Make sure you test strings with different line breaks (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n\r`) for different OSs

Comment: So you propose to use string literals in unit tests? Even if they are loooong (e.g. 200 lines?)

Comment: It's a matter of convenience. If you believe they are long enough to put in an external file, and start dealing with I/O in tests then do that. Otherwise, yes, keep them in the tests, but organize them nicely.

Answer (score 2):

For LARGE strings, I would use files. The performance is plenty fast enough for unit tests. For that small trade-off, you:

1. Don't have to worry about escaping characters
2. Can diff the content in source control
3. Can validate the documents independently (ie, xml/html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a scripting language to code your tests.

[JRuby](http://jruby.codehaus.org/) and [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) support HERE documents that make it easier to define a big string that spans multiple lines

```
# In JRuby
mystring = <<EOS
This is a long string that
spans multiple lines.
EOS

# In Groovy
def mystring = """This is a long string that
spans multiple lines."""
```

This will also make your test code more easy to write as both languages have a lot of shortcuts that help write simpler code (but some might say less robust which does not matter as much if it is only unit testing code).

Comment: I don't get your idea. Why should I _script_ a test for a java class?

Comment: Not script, but to write the actual test in Groovy/JRuby. Not sure about JRuby, but you have java interoperability in Groovy, and thus can test you classes using Groovy.

Comment: Text Blocks are now in JDK 15 -> https://openjdk.org/jeps/378

Answer (score 0):

If you repeatedly use characters that are difficult to express in literal Strings (such as `"`, `\`, characters not in `[ -~]`), then you might want to consider doing a quick find-and-replace on the string before using it. For instance, if you use \ a lot, then you might wirte a function to exchange \ and /. You might use a multi-character sequence to represent accented characters.

However, there is obvious danger in ending up with a solution out of proportion to the problem. Sometimes `\u####` is just easier.

If you are going for non-Java files, I suggest opening them as resources (`Class.getResourceAsStream`/`getResource`) rather than as loose files.